# Access Query Design - Complex Criteria?

Tags: ms-access, union, criteria

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a query.

Let's say I have two tables

[image]

In the query, I want the [Carrier] value to be 'IRT'. When [Co State] = [Lic State], I want the [Line] to display, but in the case of where SC and TN have two different line entries I need only the 'M' value to show.

A sample result would be like this: 
[image]

The table data is just a fake sample. The real data includes all 50 states and some [Lic State]s would have one value and a few would have two.

Is there an easy way to create these results with one query, or would it be best to create one query that omits the [Lic State] of 'SC' and 'TN', and one that only includes 'SC' and 'TN' that have a [Line] of 'M', and then take the SQL of both queries and join them via UNION?

Comment: Are SC and TN the only states with special requirements when two values exist? It is always best to post data rather than pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on the mobile, and did that just for fun, yeah....  it is not clean bur the idea is there.

You need to use group by because you only want one record per state.

Select first (carrier), first ( Costate), iif(count ( line)>1,"M", first (line)) 
from (select costate from t2 where licstate="irt") left join t1 on Costate=licstate 
group by costate

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Aggregate Functions. And you can Aggregate over IIFs. So if you group by CoState and count 1 for every record with an M you can use an IIF on the aggregated value and give back an M if you need and otherwise give back the first value (because as of your question there will be only one value):

```
SELECT Tabelle2.Carrier, Tabelle2.CoState, IIf(Max(IIf([Tabelle1].[Line]="M",1,0))=1,"M",First([Tabelle1].[Line])) AS Line
FROM Tabelle1 INNER JOIN Tabelle2 ON Tabelle1.LicState = Tabelle2.CoState
GROUP BY Tabelle2.Carrier, Tabelle2.CoState
HAVING (((Tabelle2.Carrier)="IRT"));
```

So its three steps: the inner IIF gives back a 1 for every recordset with an M. The aggregation converts that to a 1 for Records that should come back with an M and a 0 for others - and finally the outer IIF works on the aggregated function and gives back either an M or the Line-Value. Since you are grouping, you need also to aggregate over that value - which you do with the FIRST-directive.

Comment: Both answers (Johanness's and user6788933's) work for what I want to do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the given data they indeed do the same. user6788933s solution uses a subquery (SELECT FROM (SELECT...)) which I think you should avoid if you have other possibilities, because it can be very slow and memory-consuming. If you use count(line) it works only if there is always a second column on costates with an M column.